# Can anyone explain AOL Mail (Verizon.net) Sending Limits, and what we can do about them?

Tags: email, thunderbird, aol

As an AV integrator, I overhauled the network for a small church, which barely understands the Internet. Now, whenever they have general computer problems, I get the call. I'm willing to help but I'm looking for the best path forward here.

They have an @verizon.net email address, which is now hosted by AOL Mail. Note that they are no longer a Verizon customer, but the email is still active. They've been using Thunderbird to send/receive email for years.

When it comes time for them to send the weekly newsletter out, the church secretary sends a BCC email to a Thunderbird list. I do not know how many recipients are in each send, but I don't think it's a lot. It's a tiny church.

Suddenly, it seems that every email sent is blocked by the SMTP server, but in Thunderbird, we don't get a detailed error. I can send single messages to myself in the TO field.

I'm trying to find more info on what the actual limits are, or if restrictions were suddenly put into place. It doesn't seem like I can email AOL support without paying for the premium support. I found some info here (https://help.aol.com/articles/aol-mail-limits-on-sending-bulk-mail).

Now, I do have experience with mail servers, but don't know what the best path forward for them is. For our company's mail, I've used SendGrid verified my domain. If I were to point them to this or something like ConstantContact or Mailchimp, would those messages just originate from a generic provider address? Do those services work standalone from whatever email address they generally receive email on? I'm guessing this is possible as long as we don't care how the message shows up in the "FROM" field to recipients.

Thanks!